# Debugging HTML and XML

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm Trying to extract information from XML using XPath and put it into a page, But I'm not able to get a result. I would like to know whether there is any kind of debugger for HTML too so that I can track down the process and also the variables I have specified in the script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you extracting? What is hosting your XPath? You say script - what language?

Comment: Well, aside from posting us your current code, chrome has Developer Tools, Firefox has Firebug, and if you want to go there, IE has developer tools as well.

Comment: @Oded I'm using javascript to extract information from a xml file of my own (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes_first)

Comment: @Daedalus I'm looking for debuggers that runs every line and provides an option to trace variables, kind of like eclipse used to develop applications.

Comment: The developer tools for Chrome and Firefox provide full debugging of javascript code, including code calling xpath. Need I also point out that believing what you read at w3schools is not a wise choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is *Javascript* code that is pulling data out of the DOM. As such, the debugger you need is a debugger for Javascript in your browser. For Firefox, that's Firebug. For Chrome, that's just the developer tools. For IE, well, I can't help you.